# copy data from specific cell in a sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are few queries which are somewhat similar but I'm unable to get a solution from those.

In my mainsheet I'm importing data from a webpage using Importdata function in the mainsheet. The data in the webpage changes every 5mins and so the cell value A50 changes every 5 mins in the mainsheet.

Now I want to write a google app scrip function that will copy the value from A50 of mainsheet to another sheet in the cell A1,A2,A3,A4,A5.......and so on and have a timestamp correspondingly in B1,B2,B3,B4,B5....and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onEdit()` trigger function to do this. When an edit happens in cell `A50` check if cell and sheets are correct then read value and save into target sheet. Below code does that. Change the sheet names as shown in comment.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // check if active range is A50 or not
  var rangeStr = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (rangeStr != 'A50') return;
  // get Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get sheets
  var mainSheetNames = ['main sheet name', 'main sheet name', 'main sheet name']; // change here
  var mainSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (mainSheetNames.indexOf(mainSheet.getName()) == -1) return;
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target sheet name'); // change here
  // get value
  var value = e.value;
  // set values
  targetSheet
    .getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2)
    .setValues([[value, new Date().toLocaleString()]]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm getting the following error when I run the code.

TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined

Comment: if you **normally** run code, `e` is undefined, it wont work. you have to edit an A50 cell in main sheet to test

Comment: Oh yes it’s working, as per the code the value gets filled in A1 of the targetsheet and the time stamp in A2 but I want timesheet in B1, when I tried editing the code in the last line I’m not getting it correct. If I have more than 1 mainsheet please guide me as to what needs to be changed in the code.

Comment: edited code. put main sheet names in the array and try

Comment: I'm not getting any output in the cell in the targetsheets :( will try to figure out if I'm doing anything wrong and get back to you.

Comment: If I go and change the cell value A50 manually and hit enter the value gets updated in the target sheet. If the data is refreshing automatically its not getting updated in the target sheet..

Comment: have you put all the main sheet names in array ?

Comment: Yes I did and now for testing I have kept only one sheet and trying that too still, the result comes to the target sheet on manually entering it in cell A50 of mainsheet.